# Iteration in drools to count specific object value

Tags: java, drools

Hi New to Drools and stuck where I need to iterate over a list of objects and do the count and if count is beyond threshold number then assign some value.

requirement: Count the number of employees whose department matches "HR" and if it goes beyond a number 10 then assign specific band to the department.
I have used below code however it only gives the matches not sure how check the count and then assign the tag.

`rule "Less Than or Equal 10 Employee"
dialect "mvel"
when 
    company : CompanyFact($listOfEmployees: employees)
    employee : EmployeeFact(departmentType == "HR") from $listOfEmployees
then
    company.setDepartmentBand("ABC");
end`

The outcome of the same is only resulting if department is HR its assigning the band whereas I am looking if more than 10 employees from HR then only give the band as "ABC"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `accumulate` or `collect`, depending on how complex your condition is.

```
rule "More than 10 HR employees"
when
  company: CompanyFact($listOfEmployees: employees)
  List(size > 10) from collect(EmployeeFact(departmentType == "HR") from $listOfEmployees)
then
  company.setDepartmentBand("ABC");
end
```

I used `collect` in this example because it's a simple "get a subset". If you wanted to get a collection of properties, average/max/mean, or something more complicated, you'd use `accumulate`.